# Term query for perception disconnection

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word in English (perhaps but not necessarily in medical jargon) to describe the disconnection between two related bodily perceptions, e.g.:

- to feel tired, but not sleepy
- to be hungry, but to have no appetite

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Matt. You need to flesh this out a little. For example, one of the requirements for using the SWR tag is that you _must_ include a sample sentence with a blank space indicating the POS and usage of the word. From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead ... "

Comment: That's called "being conflicted" or "being of two minds."  By the way, I don't think you can be hungry but have no appetite.  You can be tired but not sleepy, which either results from physical tiredness but not mental or from insomnia, both of with are usually referred to as "exhaustion."

Comment: I am assuming that to be hungry but have no appetite means that although you are hungry, no food that you consider eating—even those you normally enjoy—appeals to you in the moment?

Comment: @Cascabel Oh sorry, thank you. What is "POS"? I'm actually not sure, I was wondering if there's a common term, so I can't really think if an example sentence. Perhaps for example something like if I'm hungry or tired, but don't have an appetite or am not sleepy, respectively, I'm feeling...Out of sorts?

Comment: @Jason exactly. Not that you physically can't, just that nothing appeals to you in that moment. I'm sorry, it's very vague.

Comment: @MattS. Sorry...POS is "Part Of Speech" i.e. noun, verb, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think part of the term you're looking for is "dissonance" which the Oxford Dictionaries defines as "[Lack of agreement or harmony between people or things.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dissonance)"

There is such a thing as "Sensory Dissonance", but that seems more related to physical sensations [not jiving with reality](https://myhalfof.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/sensory-dissonance/) (such as when you get into a cold pool because it seems warmer than being in the wind, even though it is in fact colder.)  This is the closest I could come up with, however.

("Cognitive dissonance" is something else altogether, the ability to hold two or more contradictory opinions or beliefs.)